# C++ template generalization for const type

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-specialization

I am doing a small research here, which requires at some stage, that I have different classes doing (or not doing) operation on some data, depending on its constness.

A small example is like this (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75c29cddbe6d8ef6)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class funny
{
public:
    funny(T& a) : v(a) {v -= 1; }
    virtual ~funny() { v += 1; }
    operator T() {return v;}

private:
    T& v;
};

#define V(a) funny<decltype(a)>(a)

int main()
{
    char t[] = "ABC"; // <-- HERE

    if( V( t[0] ) == (char)'A')
    {
        std::cout << "Pass" << t[0];
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No Pass" << t[0];
    }
}
```

Now, comes the question:

if I modify the line marked `<-- HERE` to be

```
const char t[] = "ABC";
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'funny<T>::funny(T&) [with T = const char&]':
main.cpp:21:7:   required from here
main.cpp:7:28: error: assignment of read-only location '((funny<const char&>*)this)->funny<const char&>::v'
  funny(T& a) : v(a) {v -= 1; }
                      ~~^~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'funny<T>::~funny() [with T = const char&]':
main.cpp:21:7:   required from here
main.cpp:8:27: error: assignment of read-only location '((funny<const char&>*)this)->funny<const char&>::v'
  virtual ~funny() { v += 1; }
                     ~~^~~~
```

Which is totally understandable, since I try to modify a constant. Compiler is right here. However, I really need this to work also for const data, so I tried to create a const specialization of the template:

```
template <class T>
class funny <T const>
{
public:
    funny(const T& a) : v(a) {}
    operator T() {return v;}

private:
    const T& v;
};
```

But regardless, the compiler does not find it, and still tries to compile the non-const version.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: As you can see in the error message, `T` is deduced as `const char&`, which is a reference type and hence not const-qualified (`T` is `X&` where `X` is `const char`). This is because `t[0]` is an expression and as an expression, an lvalue. `decltype(e)` of such an expression yields an lvalue-reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiles if you change:

```
template <class T>
class funny <T const>
```

to:

```
template <class T>
class funny <const T&>
```

Comment: Indeed it does :) Thanks!

Comment: Note that this works because `decltype(t[0])` is a reference. This wouldn't work for just some `const char`. @Miles answer is more robust.

Comment: @TartanLlama I agree

Answer (score 4):

`decltype(t[0])` deduces to `const char&`, which doesn't match your `const char` specialization.  You have two options:

1) Change your specialization to `template <class T> class funny <T const&>`.  That will work for this case, but won't work for `const int FOO = 42; V(FOO);`.

2) Change your `V` macro to always deduce to a non-reference type:

```
#define V(a) funny<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(a)>::type>(a)
```